twilio notify rest service showed successfully sent status but I didn't get the sms
I am developing an integration with twilio service, and I have a question regarding sending 1 message to several users at once in 1 api call. I've already familiarized myself with the documentation and tried some working options. I also perused the available questions and answers on Stackoverflow, but the information is pretty much outdated( how to send single message to multiple numbers , sending/receiving multi recipient sms) and also it is not consistent.
According to the official documentation I could use the notifay service notify service as it provides a possibility to send a notification to Bindings in the request. Here is the code I've implemented:
 string accountSid = "your_accountSid";
 string authToken = "your_authToken";

 const string serviceSid = "your_serviceSid";

 TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

 var notification = NotificationResource.Create(
     serviceSid,
     toBinding: new List<string> { "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+phone1\"}",
     "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+phone2\"}", },
     body: "Hello from Twilio");

 Console.WriteLine(notification.Sid);

To make this code work and not generate errors, I made the following steps:

register a trial account on twilio.
confirm the phone number from which you are registering.
buy sender number
create sms-service
add sender number to sms-service
create notify-service

In the logs of twilio, I see that the status of 2 sms messages is sent, however the messages were not delivered (I used my personal cell phone numbers).
I see from the site's offiicial documentation that the notify service is no longer available(notify-api-eol, transitioning off notify) to new subscribers, but the fact that my messages were sent and I didn't get any errors, nor did I receive the sms messages themselves confuses me )
The only solution I can see right now is to iterate through the recipient list in a loop and send messages one at a time, which doesn't look like a good solution to me:
string accountSid = "your_accountSid";
string authToken = "your_authToken";

var allReceipeents = new List<string>() { "phoneNumber1", "phoneNumber2", "phoneNumberN" };
try
{
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    foreach (var item in allReceipeents)
    {
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
        body: "Hello from Eugene!",
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+phoneNumber"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(item)
        );
        //logging
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //log error
}

My stack is: .NET 8, Twilio package version 7.0.5
The questions I still have are: does the notifay service work, if not, is there any way to send a message to multiple users in 1 api call, and why if the service doesn't work I can see in the console that messages were successfully sent, could these problems be related to the fact that I am using a trial account?
Thanks in advance for any advice or comments.
Update1: Probably this( twilio news2024) SO question gives me some answers.
